# ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-full

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have followed all the steps but still getting error. please help me out

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245984/ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-full/) by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To cite the [Installation instructions for indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu):

> ROS Indigo ONLY supports Saucy (13.10)
> and Trusty (14.04) for debian
> packages.

On 16.04 you need to install kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2017-05-12**:
Completely correct! On 16.04 only Kinetic and above is supported.

When you want to use Indigo you need to install Ubuntu 14.04